# Testing a 2D point cloud for banana shape

Tags: hypothesis-testing, pattern-recognition

I have many point clouds of a small size (say <200 points) in 2D. Some of them are isotropic and can be modelled as a single point. Others are elongated and curved so that they can reasonably be fit to the apex of a parabola. The dispersion seems to be of the same order for all clouds and there can be a fraction of outliers (say 10%).

Here are four samples, of diminishing size. The bottom right is an isotropic case.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to distinguish the circular clouds from the parabolic ones. I can probably use the regression coefficient, but I am looking for alternatives, with two purposes:

1) have a low computational cost (as the test has to be repeated hundred thousand times), and

2) go as far as possible as regards the classification of banana vs. "cherry" for small clouds or for larger dispersion, i.e. distinguishing cases like 3 and 4.

The method can require the knowledge of the dispersion, but it is better if not.

Comment: What do you mean with "can require the knowledge of dispersion". Do you have some measure (like covariance) precomputed?

Comment: Currently I don't have such a measure. I can think of three strategies: 1) work with a reasonable dispersion value chosen once for all (accepting that it won't work so well in some cases); 2) compute a global dispersion estimate valid for all clouds (possibly taken from a sample of clouds); 3) compute an estimate per cloud. In the latter two cases, I need a way to estimate the dispersion for the bananas.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the mean of each cloud and then assess the shape of the point density as a function of distance $f(d)$ from the cloud's mean.

- If it's a circular cloud the resulting curve will probably resemble an exponentially decreasing curve, e.g. $f(d) \approx \alpha e^{-\beta d}$.
- If it's a banana it will probably resemble a Gaussian centered at some $d > 0$ since the highest density is not at $d=0$ for bananas.

To distinguish between circle and banana, find a rough estimate for $\max_{d} f(d)$. If this is close enough to $0$ you have a circle, otherwise it's a banana.

Comment: Interesting. I can replace my parabolic model by an elliptic one, having its center on the left edge, and by normalizing the coordinates, turn it to a half circle. Then my problem could be rephrased as testing hypothesis $d=0$ vs $d>0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you have found a good model (that discriminates nicely), you can then try subsampling each cluster. Then you check the significance using only a small number of samples and accept if it is sufficient; if your model gives only low significance you can increase the number of points.

Comment: @ziggystar: good idea, as I need to minimize the cost. This will increase the probability of misclassification, right ? (because the samples will have more chance to be in a deceptive configuration by accident.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's why you need a method to judge the quality of your classification (e.g. probability of false positive/false negative). If you have this, you can adaptively increase your sample size.

Comment: @ziggystar: how can I derive an estimator of the classification trustworthiness for a given sample ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust This depends on your model. E.g. the *p-value* of hypothesis tests is the false positive probability.